# socket.io - require (socket.io)(http)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When I require `socket.io` package, why must I pass the entire `http` package?

Maybe because socket.io must be connected with my http server?

This is the code:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
    var express = require("express");
    var app = new express();
    var http = require("http").Server(app);
    var io = require("socket.io")(http);


    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

    // listen for events
    io.on("connection", function () { // first arguments is the name of the event
        console.log("User connected via socket.io");
    })

    http.listen(port, function () {

        console.log("Server started");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every WebSocket connection starts with an http connection.

So in your case, you are attaching your socket server to an existing http server (the same than your express app).

But you could have an independent socket server, that would go like :

```
var io = require('socket.io')(5000);
```

In this case, the socket server will run as a separate server.

If what you're trying to achieve is a websocket connection within your website,  for a chat or otherwise, it's better to attach it to express, so you have access to all the req/res data.

Comment: Perfect!!!! so i understand how socket.io is connected at the server! I studying socket.io ... thank you so much! Is very clear :)